# How i can implement in my query for expected output

Tags: mysql

In this query only one record is showing pls help...

```
("SELECT p.project_name, p.category, p.status, count(b.developer_id) AS developer_id 
 FROM project p , bidding b 
 WHERE p.project_id=b.bid_id AND p.client_reg_id='"+LID+"'");
```

Comment: Did you check if in your table there is more than one record with the provided filters?  Post the table, the data, the SQL (Real SQL with LID, not the PHP you wrote), and maybe someone can point you something.

Comment: yes more than one records exist in a bidding table and i want count of developer_id

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is an aggregate function, will always group several registers to one register. Remove it from your query and you'll see all the rows. More info in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

```
("SELECT p.project_name, p.category, p.status, b.developer_id AS developer_id 
  FROM project p , bidding b 
  WHERE p.project_id=b.bid_id AND p.client_reg_id='"+LID+"'");
```

### EDIT

Try this:

```
SELECT p.project_name, p.category, p.status, count(b.developer_id) AS developer_bid_count
FROM project p
INNER JOIN bidding b 
ON p.project_id = b.bid_id
WHERE p.client_reg_id='"+LID+"'
GROUP BY p.project_id
```

I'm assuming that project_id is the primary key in your `project` table. As we specify the `group by` field, if this field is the primary key, the query will return one row per project, counting how many bids there are per developer

Comment: this query stores developer_id but hear i want count of the developer_id

Comment: @TUSHARTAJNE, try the query I proposed, if you specify the group by I think you'll get what you want